# Can I Assign a Specific Mod Value for unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl, std, unordered-map

In these days, I'm learning Hashing and I come along with a question, I know I can assign a custom hash for unordered_map but can I assign a custom mod value for unordered_map and if it's possible how? I've searched it on the Internet but I couldn't find the answer, but when I hashing a string, I should take modulo in its calculation and if my modulo value and unordered_map's modulo value is different, that can cause a problem, also in Competitive Programming, nearly all the hashes are hackable, and if I can assign my random mod value to unordered_map, it will be safer, so how can I solve this problem, or can I assign my value for unordered_map?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
  cin.tie(0);
    mt19937 rng(chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
    vector<int> pr, ip(1e6);
    int ind = -1;
    //Sieve
    for (int i = 2; i < 1e6; ++i) {
        if (!ip[i]) {
            if (ind == -1 && i > 1e5) ind = pr.size();
            pr.push_back(i);
            for (int j = i; j < 1e6; j += i) ip[j] = i;
        }
    } 
    const int mod = pr[uniform_int_distribution<int>(ind, pr.size() - 1)(rng)];
    struct chash {
        size_t operator ()(string x) const {
            // Hash Function with using mod value
        }
    };
    unordered_map<string, int, chash> umap;
    //assign my mod value to umap
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int val;
        string s;
        cin >> x >> val;
        umap[s] = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _custom mod_? Do you mean a function that takes a hash value and returns an index in the array of buckets? You want this index to be randomized? How could you then access the same element twice?

Comment: I mean can I use unordered map like my custom hash table, I want to unordered map's use my module value for all the elements, so they won't be randomised

Comment: I think there's some conceptual confusion here. What is a `mod value`, and why do you think `unordered_map` has one? The hashing is done only by the provided hashing function, and the map has no knowledge at all about what it does.

Comment: Why are worried about having a "hackable" hash table and making it safer? What do you want to protect it from?

Comment: molbdnilo, in codeforces, users can hack each other's solutions for points, and unsafe hash tables are sitting duck for contestants.

Comment: I thought unoreded_map needs size and a mod value for building hash table.

Comment: It needs a hash function and an equality predicate. (See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).) You can also specify the (minimal) number of buckets, which is possibly what you mean by "mod value". Note that the number of buckets may change as you modify the map.

Answer (score 0):

The "mod value" you keep talking about is simply to map the hash value to a place in the vector underlying the hash table. It is, logically, always equal to the current size of the vector.

The only knob you can tweak is the hash function, as you found.
It is supposed to return a `std::size_t` with the contract that if `KeyEqual(A, B)` then `Hash(A) == Hash(B)`.

If you want to prevent denial of service attacks via hash collisions, you have to come up with a hash function that makes it hard to find lots of keys with the same hash value. The most common approach here is to mix a per-process random seed into the hash value that cannot be easily guessed or predicted. Don't use just the process ID and `time()` output, for example, but rather base yourself off of a nanosecond-granularity timer and maybe some bytes from `/dev/random`.